# What is the problem with my Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, set, src

I have trying to change my code with .setAttribute too, the same thing appear..

In Javascript

```
document.getElementById("MyImg").src = "./sea.jpg";
```

In HTML :

```
<img src="./earth.jpg" id="MyImg">
```

Thank you for any futer answer !

Comment: please describe your problem in details

Comment: When do you run your js? It seems to be executed before document is ready and html is completely loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of **null**

The null is the important part. Your DOM search (getElementById) failed.

Some ideas off the top of my head:

1. The script is running in a different page
2. The  tag is not actually there
3. There is a misspelling in the id (looks good in your example though)

If you need an example to work off of: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_src.asp

Comment: 1. The script is on a same .html page, with the tag <script>

2 & 3. It's the same code in my topic

I realy don't understand what is the problem

Comment: Perhaps Vinserello is correct, the script might be executing before the document is ready. Place your <script> tag at the very bottom, just before the </body> tag.

Comment: Wow... just to change the position of my <script> you totaly repar my code ! 

Thank you !! :D